# Merge kubectl config into ~/.kube/config

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

To use `kubectl`(to talk to kubernetes `api-server`) with merged config,

below two commands can be used to merge kubeConfig:

`KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:/path/to/another/config.yml kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/config-new.yaml`

and then

`cp ~/.kube/config-new.yaml ~/.kube/config`

---

after running above two commands, `~/.kube/config` will have merged config

---

But, In our case, instead of using `kubectl`, we are planning for a GoLang tool that uses [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library, as part of automation.

GoLang tool maintains kubeconfig retrieved from MongoDB(every 10 minutes) and stored in `[]map[string]string`(shown below):

```
[
   {
      "name" : "cluster-1-in-gcp",
      "kubernetes-version": "1.16",
      "server": "https://192.168.10.190:6443",
      "user": "kubernetes-admin-1",
      "client-certificate": "sadfhdsjfkhsdjfklhsdjfkassdfsd",
      "client-key": "sahgjkshfgjkdf",      
   },
   {
      "name" : "cluster-1-in-aws",
      "kubernetes-version": "1.17",
      "server": "https://192.168.11.191:6443",
      "user": "kubernetes-admin-2",
      "client-certificate": "ssssshdsjfkhsdjfklhsdjfkassdfsd",
      "client-key": "pppppsahgjkshfgjkdf",
   },
   {
      "name" : "cluster-1-in-aks",
      "kubernetes-version": "1.18",
      "server": "https://192.168.11.192:6443",
      "user": "kubernetes-admin-3",
      "client-certificate": "oooossssshdsjfkhsdjfklhsdjfkassdfsd",
      "client-key": "tttttpppppsahgjkshfgjkdf",      
   },
]
```

---

`client-certificate` & `client-key` are PEM format certificates(stored as `string`)

Certificates will be stored as(shown below):

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://192.168.10.190:6443
  name: cluster-1
- cluster:
    server: https://192.168.99.101:8443
  name: cluster-2
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-1
    user: kubernetes-admin-1
  name: cluster-1
- context:
    cluster: cluster-2
    user: kubernetes-admin-2
  name: cluster-2
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin-1
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-1.crt
    client-key: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-1.key
- name: kubernetes-admin-2
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-2.crt
    client-key: /home/user/.minikube/credential-for-cluster-2.key
```

---

Seeking a Go package to merge this kubeConfig(`[]map[string]string`) to `~/.kube/config`

Does [cliendcmd](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd#example-package-MergingEverythingNoConflicts) package of `client-go` library support this merge functionality?

Comment: So, store data in `Config` and then merge using `ClientConfigLoadingRules`.... here is the reference to `Config`: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/clientcmd/api/types.go#L31

Comment: Here is an [example](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd#example-package-MergingEverythingNoConflicts) where `testConfigAlfa` is of `Config` type