# Syntax to express a connectortype as union of DBType or MessageQType

Tags: go

We have below code:

```
const (
    Mongo      DBType     = "mongodb"
    SQL        DBType     = "sql"
    KAFKA      MQType     = "kafka"
    YCQL       DBType     = "Yugabyte" 
  )

type DBType string
type MQType string
```

---

Goal is to have a type `ConnectorType` that can either be `DBType` or `MQType`

So that the data get stored in in `map[ConnectorType]bool` as:

```
{
   SQL: true,
   KAFKA: false,
}
```

---

What is the syntax to create type `ConnectorType` that can hold value of either type `DBType` or `MQType`?

Note: Something similar to C [unions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm)

Comment: `type ConnectorType any`

Comment: @CeriseLimón any mean empty interface?

Comment: `type ConnectorType interface{}` also works.

Comment: @CeriseLimón We are basically storing this information( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299344/merge-kubectl-config-into-kube-config) in mongoDB, but later, we may use sql(or any other rdbms).